# Getting this error when i run my java appium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium

When I save and run the code the compiler is showing error with respect to DesiredCapabilities I thought I might have made an error while importing the jar so I uninstalled everything and installed it once again but still the error exists.

This is the code I have written.

```
package tutorial;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File f = new File("src");
    File fs = new File (f,"tile-sdk26-debug-2.43.0-d.apk");

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus 5x");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

}

}
```

This is the error that I am getting.

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules java.client and okio export package org.openqa.selenium.internal to module tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", automationName);
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platformName);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
        capabilities.setCapability("systemPort", systemPort);
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "packageName");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
        capabilities.setCapability("fullReset","false");
        // capabilities.setCapability("app", appPath);
        Android driver = new AndroidDriver(new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/wd/hub"), capabilities));
```

This should work